# Splitting One Data Set Across Multiple Columns in Report Builder

Tags: sql, report

I am using report builder to generate letters. What I'm trying to do is have one column of values but when it reaches the end of the page, instead of creating a new page I want it to overflow to a new column to the right of the first. Alternatively, it would work if it populated the data across multiple columns before creating a new row.

Is this something that's possible?